# subset data.table columns for calculation of new value but keep all old columns + new value

Tags: r, data.table

1. I had a hard time phrasing the title of the question, so if someone can suggest a more accurate title, I would be grateful.

I have a matrix of ~100 samples and readings at ~200,000 specific locations.  The locations are string identifiers, the sample readings are numeric.  Example data:

```
library(data.table)
str_col = c("str1", "str2", "str3")
s1 = c(54.4, 19.0, 89.0)
s2 = c(46.6, 39.5, 85.2)
s3 = c(12.3, 0.2, 55.8)

dt = data.table(str_col, s1, s2, s3)
dt
   str_col   s1   s2   s3
1:    str1 54.4 46.6 12.3
2:    str2 19.0 39.5  0.2
3:    str3 89.0 85.2 55.8
```

I would like to calculate the standard deviation of the readings at each location (rows) for the sample columns (s1 - s3) while leaving out the location identifier `str_col`.

My attempt at this was:

```
dt[, -1, with=FALSE][, stdv := apply(.SD, 1, sd)]
dt
   str_col   s1   s2   s3
1:    str1 54.4 46.6 12.3
2:    str2 19.0 39.5  0.2
3:    str3 89.0 85.2 55.8
```

however this just returned the original data.table, as you can see.

I can do my desired operation in steps as follows:

```
dt_str_col = dt[,.(str_col)]
dt2 = dt[, -1, with=FALSE][, stdv := apply(.SD, 1, sd)]
dt3 = data.table(dt_str_col, dt2)
dt3
   str_col   s1   s2   s3     stdv
1:    str1 54.4 46.6 12.3 22.39695
2:    str2 19.0 39.5  0.2 19.65613
3:    str3 89.0 85.2 55.8 18.17067
```

But I was wondering if there was a way to do this by reference in data.table, similar to my first attempt `dt[, -1, with=FALSE][, stdv := apply(.SD, 1, sd)]`  ?

Comment: Also this `dt[, stdv := melt(.SD, 1L)[, sd(value), by = str_col]$V1]` maybe. OR `dt[, stdv := matrixStats::rowSds(as.matrix(.SD)), .SDcols = -1L]` with a trade-off of matrix conversion vs by row operations. Either-way, it seems to me hat you will be better off with just a matrix.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right that a matrix would be easier to work with.  I am just more familiar working with data.table than other methods at the moment, and was curious why I was having trouble with this case.  Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this would solve your problem, wouldn't it ?

```
dt[ ,  sdd := sd(.SD), by = str_col]

dt
#>    str_col   s1   s2   s3  sdd
#> 1:    str1 54.4 46.6 12.3 22.4
#> 2:    str2 19.0 39.5  0.2 19.7
#> 3:    str3 89.0 85.2 55.8 18.2
```

In case there is more than one row per str_cols (i.e. you really want to calculate the standard deviation by rows), you can do this:

```
# create a column with row positions
dt[, rowpos := .I]

dt[ ,  sdd := sd(.SD[, -1, with=FALSE]), by = rowpos]
```

Comment: Yup that does it for my main issue.... can't believe I didn't think of this.  So basically in this case there is no need to subset... however what if there were 2 str_cols ?

Comment: Great, thanks!  But why do you have to create a new column of row positions instead of using `by = .I`   ?

Comment: Good question. I don't know exactly why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with the data.table package, but this can be done in one step using data frames:

```
dt = data.frame(str_col, s1, s2, s3)
dt

dt$stdv <- apply(dt[,c(2:4)], 1, FUN = sd)
dt

  str_col  s1   s2   s3     stdv
1    str1 54.4 46.6 12.3 22.39695
2    str2 19.0 39.5  0.2 19.65613
3    str3 89.0 85.2 55.8 18.17067
```

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it used data.table as asked in the question, however I agree that your method would work also.  Thanks.

Comment: Totally! And it's an elegant solution too! :)